# SpringBoard failed to launch application with error: 5

Tags: ios

My iPhone application suddenly stopped launching in dev mode.
When I launch in simulator it pops up a dialog: SpringBoard failed to launch application with error: 5
There are tons of references on the web about error 3 and 7, but not the 5. I tried to follow the suggestions for the 3 and the 7, clean up the app, remove it from the simulator, restart the xcode etc... -- does not help. Can anybody shed some light about this mysterious error 5 and how to overcome it?

Comment: When i try to run the app on a device, it pops up a dialog: Could not launch “MyApp”. Disabled. This message is even more mysterious then the error 5. Any suggestions?

Comment: Errors from the iOS Simulator are logged to the system log, so open up Console.app: does it have any additional logging about this? This sounds vaguely like a `launchd` issue, but it's difficult to say for sure.

Answer (score 6):

After a while the issue came back, so digging into it, revealed, that I must have accidentally turned on location simulation option in the Run configuration as well as Background fetch (launch due to background fetch event). I was playing with the background fetch and the location events, but decided not to use it after all. Turning those off in the run scheme brought my app back to live.

Comment: The culprit is background-fetch being turned on. But I had not turned it in under the different github branch which it picked it off..

Comment: Since two days I was having this issue. Finally found the soulution. It was because of "background fetch" event.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem 2 hours ago then I closed the iOS simulator and Xcode then run it again it worked perfectly try it maybe it will work.

Comment: The same thing -- Error 5 on the simulator and Application disabled on the device. I will try rebooting my mac, will let you know if that helps.

Comment: Interesting, after the computer reboot, I started having error 3 running in simulator -- very promising.

Comment: Nope. Cleared the app from the simulator, forced closed the simulator. Relaunching the app -- back at Error 5 which no one know what it means, frustrating. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 2):

So, here is the answer. It's got something to do with the background location service. Apparently it was disabled for my application. Once I removed it from the Info.plist -- things started clicking again. Put it back -- the same exact issue. One would hope, the messages I got would be a bit more user friendly. Anyways, thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to dmitryame's answer, solving this issue for me was only accomplished by **unchecking**  "Launch due to a background fetch event"only by Under Edit Scheme / Run Configuration.

Below is an image of the culprit causing the error message in my case:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quit Simulator and clean Xcode. The fresh build will not show this Alert again. The possible reason for this might be switching between 64-bit simulator and 32-bit simulator.